# Como abro una ventada donde le pregunte donde quiere guardar un archivo?

Tags: java, aplicación-escritorio

hay alguna forma diferente a un JFileChooser de abrir una ventana donde le pregunte al usuario donde quiere guardar un archivo

Answer (score 0):

Podrias probar con [XFileDialog](https://code.google.com/archive/p/xfiledialog/). Todavía no lo he probado mucho, pero vale la pena evaluarlo